# Getting an error while animating marker on IOS in react-native

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-maps

I am getting an error while I am using `busLocation.timing(newCoordinate).start()` for marker animation.

```
animateBus = (updatedBuslocation) => {

    const { busLocation } = this.state;
    const newCoordinate = {
        latitude: updatedBuslocation.latitude,
        longitude: updatedBuslocation.longitude
    };

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        if (this.busMarker) {
            this.busMarker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate(newCoordinate, 0);
        }
    } else {
```

> ```
>        busLocation.timing(newCoordinate).start();
> ```

```
    }

}

// initial bus location state is like 

busLocation: new AnimatedRegion({
                latitude: 0.0,
                longitude: 0.0,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
            }),
```

**THE ERROR IS. =>.

> busLocation.timing

is not a function**

Comment: please can you outline the error you are getting.

Comment: I am an error  that   buslocation.timing is not a function